# Why is the SQL included in the URL of CartoDB visualizations?

Tags: carto

I noticed that the URL of CartoDB visualizations include the parameter `sql=` with the SQL statement for that visualization:

```
http://lifewatch-inbo.cartodb.com/viz/b43fa5a6-7dd0-11e3-ba2a-5f9e077d1162/embed_map?title=true&description=true&search=false&shareable=true&cartodb_logo=true&layer_selector=false&legends=true&scrollwheel=true&sublayer_options=1&sql=SELECT%20%0AST_MakeLine(the_geom_webmercator%20ORDER%20BY%20date_time%20ASC)%20AS%20the_geom_webmercator,%20%0ACASE%0AWHEN%20date_time%20%3E%3D%20'2013-05-28'%20AND%20date_time%20%3C%20'2013-06-25'%20THEN%20'1.%20Egg%20incubation'%0AWHEN%20date_time%20%3E%3D%20'2013-06-25'%20AND%20date_time%20%3C%20'2013-07-24'%20THEN%20'2.%20Chick%20rearing'%0AELSE%20'3.%20Postfledging'%0AEND%20as%20behaviour%0AFROM%20three_gulls%0AWHERE%20bird_name%20%3D%20'Eric'%0AAND%20outlier%20IS%20NULL%0AGROUP%20BY%20behaviour%0AORDER%20BY%20behaviour&sw_lat=50.790527850939384&sw_lon=2.2449874877929688&ne_lat=51.76975203254081&ne_lon=5.587577819824219
```

However, these parameter seems optional, as the visualization works fine without the parameter:

```
http://lifewatch-inbo.cartodb.com/viz/b43fa5a6-7dd0-11e3-ba2a-5f9e077d1162/embed_map?title=true&description=true&search=false&shareable=true&cartodb_logo=true&layer_selector=false&legends=true&scrollwheel=true&sublayer_options=1&sw_lat=50.790527850939384&sw_lon=2.2449874877929688&ne_lat=51.76975203254081&ne_lon=5.587577819824219
```

Changing the SQL on CartoDB will update the existing visualization and render the value of `SQL=` outdated, so I was wondering why it is included at all?

Answer (score 1):

It's outdated, it was used in the previous version of cartodb. The SQL is not included in the viz.json which is fetch when the embed_map is loaded

Comment: Are there plans to remove the parameter from the "Publish" functionality in CartoDB?

Comment: I will add it as a ticket right now

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you want to display 3 different states of the same visualization. Then you can embed the same code and use the same visualization but you just change that parameter.
Does that make sense?

Comment: But it seems the SQL parameter is ignored, so it would just show the same visualizations 3 times, or not?